# How can I map Ctrl-TAB to something in Vim?

Tags: vim

I'd like to map `Ctrl-TAB` to `gt` in Vim so that I can switch tabs with one keystroke.

I tried...

```
nmap <C-T> gt
nmap <C-Tab> gt
nmap <C-TAB> gt
```

That didn't work. How do you say "the tab key" in Vimese?

Comment: It looks to me like `Ctrl-Tab` is two keystrokes, just like `gt`. Also, Ctrl-PageDown is an alternate keystroke for tab navigation (along with Ctrl-PageUp).

Comment: After enough time spent trying to get it to work (terminal issues), I ended up going with: `nmap <C-l> gt` and `nmap <C-h> gT`. Didn't know aoubt Ctrl-PageDown/Up, thx Greg.

Answer (score 74, accepted):

It can be mapped in gvim, but terminals don't see a difference between `<Tab>` and `<C-Tab>`.

Comment: +1 This explains what I saw in MacVim vs. vim (in a terminal).

Answer (score 26):

You can't. Tab is already a control key, `<C-i>`.

Comment: Erm, is there a reason this shouldn't be used? `map <c-i> :bn<CR>` (next buffer, emulating tab switching) is what I was trying to do and it does what I wanted so far.

Comment: Oh, just kidding, I see what you meant. Tab *is* <c-i>, I misread.

Comment: This can also be seen on the ASCII table: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#Control_characters

Comment: In the context of a terminal session, the tab key generates ASCII code 9, the same as Control-I. However, a GUI program (e.g. gvim) can detect control-tab - see the answer from YuGiOhJCJ

Answer (score 13):

It works on gVim.
Just add this at the end of your ~/.gvimrc file:

```
" Add keyboard shortcuts
map <C-Tab> gt
map <C-S-Tab> gT
```

Answer (score 4):

I use the `mintty` terminal in `cygwin`. This terminal has an option of using `ctrl-tab` to cycle between the various instances of cygwing or alternatively, you can use to go to the next or previous `screen` window (so `ctrl-tab` does the same as `ctrl-a+n` and `s-ctrl-tab` does the same as `ctrl-a+p`. This last behavior is very convenient in my opinion.
Check

[Using_Ctrl+Tab_to_switch_session_in_GNU_Screen](http://code.google.com/p/mintty/wiki/Tips#Using_Ctrl+Tab_to_switch_session_in_GNU_Screen)

Comment: This functionality can also be used to switch tabs in Vim: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54596137/68086.

Answer (score 2):

## git-bash (mintty)

First, disable the *Switch window* option in *Options* > *Keys*.  Then you can use the following maps.

**Note: you cannot simply copy and paste these into your `.vimrc`.  Instead, where `^[[1;6I` is, you need to press [`Ctrl-V`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/366875/124008) while in insert mode and then type `Ctrl-Shift-Tab`.  The same goes for `^[[1;5I` and `Ctrl-Tab`.**

```
nnoremap ^[[1;6I :tabprevious<CR>
nnoremap ^[[1;5I :tabnext<CR>
inoremap ^[[1;6I <Esc>:tabprevious<CR>
inoremap ^[[1;5I <Esc>:tabnext<CR>
```

Comment: How to configure Vim to understand `<Esc>[1;5I` as a `Ctrl+Tab` value?

Comment: I also have a problem with Ctrl+Tab shortcut. It works well for Ctrl+Shift+Tab shortcut only.

Answer (score 1):

If you are on a mac, then you can use [Karabiner](https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/index.html.en) to remap keys. Here is how you can do it in steps:

1. Open Karabiner preferences > Misc & Uninstall tab, click "open private.xml" to open it in editor of choice
2. Inside the `<root>` node add the following configuration

   ```
   <item>
     <name>c-tab to s-tab LEFT</name>
     <identifier>private.ctabtostabl</identifier>
     <autogen>
   __KeyToKey__
   KeyCode::TAB, ModifierFlag::CONTROL_L,
   KeyCode::TAB, ModifierFlag::SHIFT_L
     </autogen>
   </item>
   <item>
     <name>c-tab to s-tab RIGHT</name>
     <identifier>private.ctabtostabr</identifier>
     <autogen>
   __KeyToKey__
   KeyCode::TAB, ModifierFlag::CONTROL_R,
   KeyCode::TAB, ModifierFlag::SHIFT_R
     </autogen>
   </item>
   ```
3. After saving the xml file, go back to Karabiner preferences, this time to "Change Key" tab, push the "Reload XML" button, and check the newly minted options. Now your control-tab should become shift-tab!

[image: step 3 screenshot]

Comment: How would you write that in Json now that karabiner had to remake itself from scratch?

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me in MacVim

```
:map <C-Tab> gt
```

It works in command mode. Not in Edit mode.
It does not work in vim in my terminal.

Comment: It works on insert mode if you use `imap` instead of `map`.

Answer (score 0):

I got this working with Konsole 19.12.3. Here's how:

1. Menu-bar -> Settings -> Configure Keyboard Shortcuts
2. Delete the existing keybinds for Ctrl+Shift+Tab and Ctrl+Tab by binding them to "None"
3. Menu-bar -> Settings -> Profiles -> Edit -> Keyboard -> Edit
4. Bind `Backtab+Ctrl+Ansi` (or probably just Backtab+Ctrl-Ansi if you have a non-ANSI keyboard) to `\E[27;6;9~`. Use the test area to confirm that the binding is working; it should echo the sequence above. Delete any binding that conflicts with it.
5. Bind `Tab+Ctrl+Ansi` (or non-ANSI equivalent) to `\E[27;5;9~`.
6. In your .vimrc add your bindings in the form of: `nnoremap <C-Tab> :tabn<CR>` and `nnoremap <C-S-Tab> :tabp<CR>`